# Changing account name and password on Windows Services remotely

Tags: powershell, service

I need to write a program / script to change the account name and password on certain services running on a remote server. I intend to do it with Powershell. Is that the best solution or is there something else that would be more suitable?

A quick google search brought up this script:

```
$account="domain\userName"
$password="password"

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='alerter'"
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
```

Am I mistaken in thinking the above script works on the local machine? If that is true, how do I do the same for a service on a remote machine?

Comment: pstools might be able to help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is running on your local machine. Use the -ComputerName parameter to run it on remote systems.

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='alerter'" -ComputerName Server1,Server2